# meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=6"

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, x-ua-compatible

the microsoft page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

in the "Specifying legacy document modes"  there's a table with columns:  "Browser version  | Result |  Description"

Now, if I want a page to be compatible with IE6 onwards, does this mean i should specify "IE5"  as appears in the result column ?

Is specifying anything other than one of "IE5 , IE8, IE9,IE11 " considered incorrect ?

Thx

Comment: Gosh, who's forcing you to do this? if you check the page you've referenced, there's a chapter called "Specifying multiple content attribute values". You can put any combination you want.

Comment: There is no IE6 standards mode; it was replaced by IE7 standards mode, which "broke the web" and led to document modes being introduced in IE8.  You can choose one of the document modes for IE7 or what's known as IE5 quirks mode.  Give the requirements you've specified, it sounds like the closest you're going to get is IE7 standards mode (`content="IE=7"`)  For full details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx